# Count repetition of data starting with specific value in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have `dataGridView1` containing two columns, **Col1** and **Col2**, which both contain duplicate values.

```
Col1 | Col2                  Id | Value| Repetition
===========                 =======================
2515 | 1105    ----------     1 | 2515 | 3
1105 | 2515    |button|       2 | 2508 | 1
3800 | 2208    ----------     
2515 | 1105
2508 | 3800
```

I need to count repetition of values from both columns by selecting only values starting with **25** then show the result in `dataGridView2` which consists of Columns: `Id`, `Value`, and `Repetition`, after clicking on button.

I tried the following logic but I miss the condition to select, count and show only values start with **25**. this count all values and show in 2nd grid the repetition of every value in both columns.

```
            var q1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Col1")).ToList();
            var q2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Col2")).ToList();

            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.AddRange(q1);
            list.AddRange(q2);
            var result = list.GroupBy(x => x)
            .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
            int count = 1;
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Id", "");
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Value", "");
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Repetition", "");

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add(count, item.Value, item.Count);
                count++;
            }
```

How can I count values start with **25** and show their repetition in `dataGridView2`as shown above?

Comment: It is difficult to picture what grid 1’s data looks like and how the data is duplicated. In addition, it is not very clear what you want grid 2 to contain. Can you [edit] your question to show a before-after example of what the grids would look like? It may help you if you take the SO [tour] to see how it works along with some helpful links to help you get an answer… [help] . [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: OK, you show what the first grid looks like, but what does the second (result) grid look like after the “Show repetition” button is clicked? And what logic are you using to produce it?

Comment: Given the example data you show… would not the value “2515” have a repetition count of three (3)?

Comment: Yes  @JohnG, sorry it was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

The condition I needed was the following and it works as I expected

```
var result = list.Where(x=>x.StartsWith("25")).GroupBy(x => x).Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```